# Using annotations to find setters

Tags: java, annotations

I have a situation in which I want to map a list of property changes to an object (backend side) with a lot of fields in Java.

```
public class EditableObject {
    private Object property;

    public void setProperty(String value) {
        property = value;
    }
}
```

So for example, I receive "that_property", "new_value", and I want to call propObject.setProperty("new_value"). The property names don't always match exactly the method names.

To avoid making a gigantic switch where I would map all the names and methods, I thought I would use annotations (also, this was made in Java 6, so no switch over String, resulting in a gigantic if/then/else instead) :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface EditableProperty
{
    public String[] value(); 
}


public class EditableObject {
    private Object property;

    @EditablePropery(value="that_property")
    public void setProperty(String value) {
        property = value;
    }
}
```

I then build and use such a map:

```
methodEditMap = new HashMap<String, Method>();

Method[] methods = EditableObject.class.getMethods();
for (Method method : methods) {
    EditableProperty annotEdit = method.getAnnotation(EditableProperty.class);
    if (annotEdit != null) {
        String[] props = annotEdit.value();
        for (String prop : props)
            methodEditMap.put(lProp, method);
    }
}
```

And I use such map to dynamically invoke the method associated when I want to apply a property change.

This method allows me to avoid a gigantic switch and somehow looks more "elegant" from the crazy programmer's point of view, but I'm wondering about it.

- First, it seems a little bit convoluted.
- Second, I worry there might be performance issues with the dynamic invocation compared to a big switch
- Third, I see it can disassociate the methods from their actual use, and their link will be invisible in an IDE.
- Last, are there other issues with this method that I'm not aware of?

In short, the question is to know if it is an acceptable solution, and if not not, why and what would be better.

Comment: Your approach is fine... just if you are not familiar with JavaBeans specification, you should check it as it addresses the object property binding as well.

Comment: @PavelHoral - I knew of JavaBeans for GUI objects, didn't know it extended further than that. I could check how they handle it, though, admittedly.

Comment: @PavelHoral - I read a bit the Introspector class, it seems they do that "the hard way". They identify the prefixes (get, set, is), and then take the rest of the name as the property name. So they don't really have the same issue as I do, which is that I have property names not matching the setters exactly.

Comment: *"I have property names not matching the setters exactly"*... then your approach is really the best (and simplest) you can do in your case.